# Regex replace groups multiple times

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to remove all html tags using this regex:

```
<.+>(.+)</.+>
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

And I replace like this:

```
"<b onclick=\"foo\">Foo</b> bar".replace(new RegExp("\\<.{1,}\\>(.{1,})\\</.{1,}\\>", "g"), "$1")
```

This works fine, however, this doesnt work:

```
"<b onclick=\"foo\">Foo</b> bar <b>hello</b>".replace(new RegExp("\\<.{1,}\\>(.{1,})\\</.{1,}\\>", "g"), "$1")
```

Since I get `hello`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use lazy not greedy

```
<.+?>
```

along with the `g` modifier

like this :

```
"<b onclick=\"foo\">Foo</b> bar <b>hello</b>".replace(/<.+?>/g,'');
```

output:

```
Foo bar hello
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
result = subject.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, "");
```

**Explanation**

- Match the character “<” literally `<`
- Match any character that is NOT a “>” `[^>]*`

  - Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) `*`
- Match the character “>” literally `>`